# Errno::ENAMETOOLONG when caching instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, caching

I am getting this error when trying to cache an instance variable that is an array of hashes:

```
Errno::ENAMETOOLONG
File name too long @ dir_s_mkdir
```

It is attempting to make the entire variable the name of the file:

```
File name too long @ dir_s_mkdir - /Users/johndoe/RubymineProjects/Project/tmp/cache/08D/E27/views%2Fnames%2FOrganization%2Fid%2F54%2Fnames%2FOrganization--%3EDevelopment%2Fid%2F59%2Fnames%2FOrganization--%3EDevelopment
```

I have poked around and seen other people have this problem and the solution is apparently to change how you store the cache key and I think it should look something like this:

```
Rails.cache.fetch(Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(<object>)
```

But I don't know where to put this or if it's even right.

Comment: How do you cache the variable with array of hashes ? Please add the code to the question

Comment: <% cache @organizations do%>
  stuff with organizations
<% end %>